# Zoho: Forms: Google Tag Manager events not firing

Tags: google-tag-manager, zoho

I have a form hosted by Zoho Forms that is embedded onto my website using an iframe.

The zoho form has a custom domain, setup as follows:

- My website: example.com
- Zoho Form: forms.example.com

Using Google Tag Manager (GTM) I'm trying to fire a Google Analytics 4 (GA4) event when someone submits the Zoho Form.

Zoho allows me to add the GTM container ID to my form. They also push data layer variables such as zf_submitform, zf_formview, etc.

So I have added my GTM container ID to my form, configured the events, and setup a trigger on GTM. But the tags are never triggered.

For example, I create a Tag that should fire a GA4 Event when the `zf_submitform` event is triggered. But it doesn't fire.

Even when I view the form directly in it's native URL (not embedded into my website) the event will not fire.

Also, when debugging it using GTM Preview, it has a green "tick" symbol next to the firing trigger. But the Firing Status is "Not Fired". So even their own debugger thinks that the tag should have fired, but it does not.

Here are some screenshots of that setup to show you what I have tried:

What am I doing wrong?

**The Tag:**

[image]

**The Custom Event (zf_submitform)**

[image]

**The GTM Preview Debugger**

[image]

Comment: Try some debugging:

Change the type of event to UA. See if the problem is with the settings that GA4 requires. Or even just some custom html console logging something.

Also try removing tag sequencing. Maybe it bricks the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just discovered that Zoho Forms includes an [allowList in their dataLayer variable](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/restrict).

This means only tag containers matching the `allowlist` will be fired.

Here is an example of the datalayer showing the `allowlist`:

```
{
  gtm: {
    allowlist: ["gas", "ua", "v", "c", "e"],
    uniqueEventId: 9,
    start: 1630545428319
  },
  event: "zf_onclickfield",
  zf_category: "Zoho Forms",
  zf_field: "Name",
  zf_page: "",
  zf_action: "Onclick Field",
  zf_formname: "Contact Us Form"
}
```

It is understandable that they have an `allowlist` on their container, to avoid people running custom code on their forms.

But it needs to have the new GA4 Config and GA4 Event tags added to the list for them to work.

I have sent them a support request asking them to add `gaawc` (Google Analytics 4 Configuration) and `gaawe` (Google Analytics 4 Event) to the `allowedlist` but they are dragging their feet.

**If you are using Zoho Forms and having problems with your own Google Tag Manager setup:** Check the datalayer and it's `allowlist`. If it does not have `gaawc` and `gaawe` then it means Zoho has not yet updated their GTM integration. In that case can you **please also message Zoho support with a link to this answer**, asking them to update the `allowlist` ASAP. The more people who request this change the faster they will act.